# File IO not working in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, java-io

I have a FileWriter to write a text to a file. The file is not getting created at all. I've checked the current working directory. Moreover, when I debug, the code for writing the text into the file is not getting executed at all...Have anyone experienced anything similar?

```
File ff = new File("ffile.txt");
    FileWriter frr = new FileWriter(ff);
    frr.write("hello");
    frr.close();
```

Comment: why don't you show us your code...

Comment: In the Eclipse IDE, you can explicitly specify your app's working directory in your "Run/Debug" profile(s)

Comment: @paulsm4 yes..but I am pretty sure that my file is not getting created

Comment: I checked above code on eclipse kepler on Ubuntu it worked fine.

Comment: If the file cannot be created (e.g. permissions), you should get an exception.  Worst case, do a "find" from your hard drive's root: WINDOWS: `dir/s ffile.txt`, LINUX: `find / -name ffile.txt -print 2> /dev/null`.  I strongly suspect 1) you'll find the file, and 2) it will be someplace you didn't expect ;)  IMHO...

Comment: try calling `File.getCanonicalPath()` to see where the file is being writteb,

Answer (score 0):

to create new file use `createNewFile();`

```
File ff = new File("ffile.txt");
 ff.createNewFile();
 FileWriter frr = new FileWriter(ff);
 frr.write("hello");
 frr.close();
```

Comment: Still not getting created :/

Comment: did you specify the path where to create like this C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\ffile.txt

Comment: otherwise it will create where your project workspace is..it works fine for me